# Ember data - return two resources in one request

Tags: search, ember.js, ember-data

I want to implement search for e-shop. User enters text, and API returns products AND categories which matches search phrase.

How do I get products and categories in one request ?

I'm aware I could do

```
return Ember.RSVP.hash( {
    products: this.store.find("product", {searchTerm: "banana"})
    categories: this.store.find("category", {searchTerm: "banana"})
} );
```

but isn't there a way to do it in a single request in order to have a better performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify you backend just create a new method for search `this.store.find("searchResult", {searchTerm: "banana"})`

Where searchresult would be something like

```
{ searchResult { products: [ ... ], categories: [ ... ] } }
```

Comment: Agreed.   How many requests it takes is a function of your backend, not your frontend.

Comment: As far as I know, in ember data it's possible to get a single resource of an array of items. `this.store.find("searchResult", {searchTerm: "banana"})` would generate a `GET /searchresults?query=banana` (plural) and would expect to get `{
    "searchResults": [
        {
            "products": [...]
            "categories": [...]
        },
        {
            "products": [...]
            "categories": [...]
        }
    ]
}`

If you want to get a single record, you have to send and id, so can't send query paramerers. Isn't it like that? Correct me if I'm wrong. Fiddle would also be great

Comment: Yes, but in this case you don't even have to go through ember data if you don't want to make searchResult object part of your model. Either just add a dummy-id to your query, or get the first object in the returned searchResult-array, or just an ajax call: 'this.get('store').adapterFor('application').ajax(queryUrl, 'GET')'. Personally i would go with picking first searchResult in returned searchResult array.

Comment: Not sure is getting first item of array was the issue but if so just use (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property_firstObject).

Comment: Re-read your question again, the returned result would be an array of searchResults containing only one item.